# How to make button inside a stacklayout clickable but make the rest of the items and the stacklayout not clickable?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a stacklayout containing many elements and one of them is a button. I want to be able to click this button but I want the other elements in there (and the stacklayout itself) to be `IsEnabled` false.

This stacklayout is on top of a map so therefor it is very important that a user can use the maps basic features on top of it.

Right now i have something like this (I have removed all attributes in there to make the code more readable)

```
<StackLayout IsEnabled = "false" >
<Image />
<Label />
<Button Clicked = "ClickEvent" />
</StackLayout>
```

So right now i set the stack to `IsEnabled`false which makes it not clickable when its on top of the map which is good, but I cannot click my button now.

How do i come around this issue?

Comment: try using InputTransparent instead

Comment: This may or not be your use case but you can also make a custom fly up on a map   http://winstongubantes.blogspot.com/2017/11/creating-draggable-sliding-up-panel-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [InputTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.inputtransparent?view=xamarin-forms) instead

> Setting InputTransparent only disables inputs and instead causes them to be passed to the VisualElement that is visually behind the element.

Comment: So i would set it to true on all elements (including the stacklayout) but not the button then? (I would set that to false) I am trying it out now to see

Comment: when i set the stacklayouts inputtransparent to true and the button inside of it to false, the button is unclickable.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the z-index of XAML elements? Wrap this in another container (e.g. `StackLayout` or `Grid`), like so:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout IsEnabled = "false" >
        <Image />
        <Label />
    </StackLayout>
    <Button Clicked = "ClickEvent" />
</StackLayout>
```

This will show the `Button` above the `StackLayout`